# Ошибка при работе с Yandex Api react

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api

Всем привет, я использую `react-yandex-maps`.

```js
const options = { json: true, results: 100, kind: 'street' };
const result = await yMapsApi?.geocode?.(searchQuery, options);
```

При `SearchQuery === 'Амиряна'` он находит улицу в `Ереване`, а при `SearchQuery === 'Амирян'` не находит, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы даже тогда когда я ввел `Амир` он нашел, такое вообще возможно?

Comment: представьте себе поисковую строку яндекс-карт, что вы видите когда вы вбивайте "амир" в контексте локации на вашем экране? Наверное, выпадающий список мест относительно того куда вы наведены на экране. Я думаю что существует метод позволяющий реализовать подобное поведение в контексте вашего проекта. Если же брать тупо самое первое совпадение именно по имён улиц по миру, то первое с чем вы столкнетесь будет улица Амир в городе Картал.

Comment: Что касается query "Амир", хорошо, но когда я отправлю query "Амирян", тоже ничего, так как точное название улицы не Амирян а Амиряна, здесь что? то же самое?

Comment: За реализованные в этом фреймворке методы не скажу. Но вообще в API Яндекса поиск не обязан вам показывать нужный адрес по частично введённой строке. Для этих целей сначала следует использовать Геосаджест, а уже выбранный форматированный адрес нужно скармливать геокодеру. https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geosuggest/